# select box in reactjs not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I have a form with a select box that gets data from the server and post it to the same server. I'm using select box from [ant design](https://ant.design/components/select/).

But that part that handles changes `handleChange()` is not working and give me this error :

> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

This is my code:

```
let optionData = [];

class ContentCountries extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 'Select',
      jsonData: 0
    };
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = {
      name: this.state.value
    }
   console.log(data);
    /*$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'https://google.com',
      data: data
    })*/
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    //ajax request
    /*$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://google.com',
      succes: function(data){
        optionData = data;
      }
    })*/
    //static example
    optionData.push('Bangalore');
    optionData.push('Pune');
    this.setState({jsonData: 1});//change the status so the select tag will get the new values(render will happen)
  }
  render() {
    var optionsTag = <Option value="">Select City</Option>  
   if(optionData.length){
     optionsTag = optionData.map((data,index) => {
                          return <Option value={data} key={index}>{data}</Option>
                          })
   }

    return (
   <form onSubmit={false}>
        <label>
          Please select city:
          <Select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
            { optionsTag}
          </Select>
        </label>
        <input type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} value="Submit" />
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using custom `Option` and `Select` components which aren't being shown here? If not, regular html elements should be lowercase. If you are using a custom `Select` component, you will need to check its docs to see what it does with an `onChange` callback.

Comment: yes i use custome select and option of ant design https://ant.design/components/form/ 
but it has nothing onChange method @JonnyBuchanan

Answer (score 3):

EDITED: Sorry, as you said, it is [`Ant Design`](https://ant.design/components/select/). However, it is almost the same with your `handleChange` function. 
Because it takes the value as the argument, not the event. So that there is no `target` property inside passed argument.

```js
handleChange(val) {
    this.setState({value: val});
  }
```